# PHP Array inserting too many records in the database

Tags: php, arrays, post, odbc, sql-insert

If i enter only 1 record. It saves only 1 record in the database which is fine.
But if i put two records of the same fields. It saves multiple records in the database which should only be two. What did i do wrong?

```
    <td>1.<input name='Description[]' type='text' required></td>

    <td><input type='text' name='Unit[]' placeholder='eg. reams,pcs,box' required></td>

    <td><input type='number' name='Quantity[]'  min='1' required></td>

    <td><input type='number' name='Cost[]' min='1' required></td>

    </tr>
```

I have a script that can add those fields again.

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($_POST["Description"] as $Description )
    {
        foreach ($_POST["Unit"] as $Unit)
        {
            foreach ($_POST["Quantity"] as $Quantity)
            {
                foreach ($_POST["Cost"] as $Cost)
                {
    $array = array($Description,$Unit,$Quantity,$Cost);
    odbc_exec($conn, "INSERT INTO MRF_Request (Qty,Unit,Description,Cost) VALUES 
    ('$Quantity' , '$Unit'  , '$Description' , '$Cost')");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: for which field in particular?

Comment: You should not have all the foreach nested. With a for loop will be enough

Comment: And if that form will be used publicly then you really have to escape the input to prevent sql injection!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over only one field and use index for others to get appropriate data:

```
foreach ($_POST["Description"] as $index => $val )
{
    $Description = $_POST['Description'][$index];
    $Unit        = $_POST['Unit'][$index];
    $Quantity    = $_POST['Quantity'][$index];
    $Cost        = $_POST['Cost'][$index];

    $array = array($Description, $Unit, $Quantity, $Cost);

    $query = "
        INSERT INTO MRF_Request (Qty, Unit, Description, Cost) 
        VALUES ('$Quantity', '$Unit', '$Description', '$Cost')
    ";

    odbc_exec($conn, $query);
}
```

You should also think about sanitizing your `$_POST` data, to make the system secure and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Not only do you need to modify your iterating technique to be a single loop and use the index of the subarray being iterated, it is essential that you defend your query from injection attacks and breakages due to single quotes in submitted values.

I've never used `odbc_`, but it seems similar to PDO's execution.

Use a single [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php) and execute it inside of your loop.

```
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO MRF_Request (Qty, Unit, Description, Cost) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
foreach ($_POST['Quantity'] as $index => $qty) {
    odbc_execute($stmt, [$qty, $_POST['Unit'][$index], $_POST['Description'][$index], $_POST['Cost'][$index]]);
}
```

Be warned, according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php

> Any parameters in parameter_array which start and end with single quotes will be taken as the name of a file to read and send to the database server as the data for the appropriate placeholder.

For the above reason and for other reasons (like maintaining clean data), you should valid/sanitize values before allowing them to be save.

One way to defend against unwanted file reading would be to call a replacement on any qualifying values like this:

```
$value = preg_replace('~^('+)(.*)\1$~', '$2', $value);
```

This would ensure that no value would both begin and end with a single quote. ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3WdzRM/1/))

- `Description` is the "loosest" input field, you should be rather ruthless about sanitizing it.
- `Unit` looks like a value where declaring a whitelist of acceptable values would be ideal.  Perhaps consider a `<select>` field in the UI -- either way validation should be done.
- `Quantity` looks like an integer, so you might call upon `ctype_digit()` and or have minimum/maximum allowances.
- `Cost` may be a float.  Depending on your preferred format, there are several techniques for validating.